# How to Change Vagrant Default Network Range?

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile, libvirt

I am using `vagrant` with `Ubuntu 14.04` and `libvirt/KVM`.

When I create VM, Vagrant add default `NIC`(management network) in range `192.168.121.0/24`. I don't want to use this network range. Yes, we can modify/delete after VM up but, I want to know if any option in `Vagrantfile` that can change or delete default network. I know how to add public or private network and configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagrant-lbvirt creates a virtual network in libvirt for managing VMs. Its default name is vagrant-libvirt and by default uses IP in range 192.168.121.0/24.

The name and address used by this network are configurable at the provider level.

management_network_name - Name of libvirt network to which all VMs will be connected. If not specified the default is 'vagrant-libvirt'.

management_network_address - Address of network to which all VMs will be connected. Must include the address and subnet mask. If not specified the default is '192.168.121.0/24'.

management_network_guest_ipv6 - Enable or disable guest-to-guest IPv6 communication.

Read more here https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt#management-network .

Answer (score 3):

To change default network you need to define new network in libvirt where you specify

```
 <domain name='my_network'/>
 <ip address='192.168.77.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
```

after that you add lines

```
libvirt.management_network_name = 'my_network'
libvirt.management_network_address = '192.168.77.0/24'
```

into provider section. Example of whole provider section:

```
config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |libvirt|
      #use the storage pool named external
      #libvirt.storage_pool_name = "external"
      libvirt.driver = "kvm"
      libvirt.memory = 1024
      libvirt.cpus = 1
      libvirt.management_network_name = 'my_network'
      libvirt.management_network_address = '192.168.77.0/24'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed answer explain how to change the network but for the second part of the question:

> delete default network

You can use a snippet like this:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
...
  config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |cfg|
    cfg.mgmt_attach = false
  end
...
end
```

You will have then to declare a private network for all vm or by vm basis.